# Converting text to bytes and writing it to file

Tags: php, byte

I want to convert one integer and one string to binary and write it to file as bytes, in the following format:

```
0x00 (id) | 0x64 (length) | 0x00 (index) | 0x01 (type) | 0x53 (value)
```

etc. I convert integers and characters with `pack('L', $value);` and then create an array with single bytes. Var dumping it gives me some trash, and I don't know how to write it to file properly. How should I do this?

Comment: Did you simply try fwrite() ?

Comment: `some trash`.... no, it isn't trash, it's byte values